# Rails Cells seems not caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-cells

I'm building a rails project, which recently needs a cache system.

I'm using Cells to build cache mechanism.

view code:

```
= cell(:payment).(:ccc)
```

viewmodel:

```
class PaymentCell < Cell::ViewModel
  cache :ccc

  def ccc
    puts '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
    @record = Record.all
    puts @record.size.to_s
    puts @record[0].category
    puts '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
    render
  end
end
```

log:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `record_table`
2
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `record_table`.* FROM `record_table`
1_20
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The question is the log always like above.
It seems that the "ccc" action executes every time.
The Cells github says :

```
For every cell class you can define caching per state. Without any configuration the cell will run and render the state once. 
In following invocations, the cached fragment is returned.
```

But the caching seems not working in my project...

Answer (score 2):

I'm so stupid.

It turned out that didn't enable  "config.action_controller.perform_caching = true"